# Getting undefined transactions with web3.js

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, nodejs, pending-transactions

I use the following script to monitor pending transactions for a certain account:

```js
const sub = web3.eth.subscribe('pendingTransactions', (err, res) => {
    if (err) console.error(err)
})

sub.on('data', async (hash) => {
    try {
        let tx = await web3.eth.getTransaction(hash)

        if (tx.to.toLowerCase() === account) {
            console.log({ address: tx.from, value: web3.utils.fromWei(tx.value, 'ether'), timestamp: new Date() })
        }

    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
    }
})
```

I'm connected to my local geth node over websockets. I expect this to just log all transactions, but a lot of times I get a null transaction:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'to' of null
    at Subscription.<anonymous> (.../index.js:18:16)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

Does anybody know why this is? I want to be able to check ALL transactions.

Comment: Just check that tx is not null before accessing tx.to.

Comment: I have rephrased the question. I actually want to check ALL the transactions, I'm not really looking for a fix, just want to know why this is.

Comment: Async events sometimes cause this type of problems, the event is fired too early or too late and the transaction was deleted or it wasn't stored yet between the event fired and it being processed by the handler. Use a queue with pending hashes that returned null, just be aware that some transactions will disappear if they were replaced or dropped.